# Marginal Probabilities for $f(x,y)=e^{-y}$ for $0≤x≤y≤∞$, $0$ otherwise

Tags: calculus, statistics

I'm having some trouble finding probabilities and marginal pdfs given a joint pdf. 
The joint pdf in question is: $f(x,y)=e^{-y}$ for $0≤x≤y≤∞$.

First, I tried to find the probability that $X≤2$ and $y≤3$, so, assuming that $y≥x$, I calculated the double integral $\int_0^2\int_x^3 e^{-y}\,dy\,dx$ to get $-2/(e^3)+2/(e^2)$.

The marginal probability functions are what really worry me, though. I know that $fx(X)=\int_{-∞}^∞ f(x,y) \, dy$ ($fy(Y)$ is calculated analogously), but for the marginal for $x$ I'm getting $1$ and for $y$ I'm getting infinity. Is this possible? It seems weird for a marginal pdf... What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you SO much for your help! :)

Comment: You're not being careful to distinguish between $x$ and $X$ or between $y$ and $Y$.  You have $f_x(X)$ where you need $f_X(x)$, and $y\le 3$ where you need $Y\le 3$, etc. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You should be setting up your marginal pdfs as follows:

\begin{align*}
f_X(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x, y) \, dy
= \int_x^\infty e^{-y} \, dy \\
f_Y(y) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x, y) \, dx
= \int_0^y e^{-y} \, dx
\end{align*}